# cannot insert to database in bowling app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my application. There is a bowling game. which to generate the final result to a name. I have a problem to insert into my database

view:

```
 <%= form_for player_index_path(@player) do |f|%>
<div class="text_field">
    <p>
    <%= f.label "Spelare namn" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p> 
    <%= f.submit "Lägg till spelare"%>
    </p>
</div>
  <%end%>
```

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
      belongs_to :result
   end

Controller:

```
  def create
 @player = Player.new(params[:player])

if @player.save
  render :action => "index"
  else
 render :action => "new"
end        
end
```

migrationen:

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
   create_table :players do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.references :results
       t.timestamps
end
```

end
end

Comment: can you show your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<%= form_for player_index_path(@player) do |f|%>
```

with

```
<%= form_for @player do |f|%>
```

Comment: when i test! so found this error!
undefined method `players_path' for #<#<Class:0x34f4c58>:0x350a768>

Comment: May we see your routes.rb and `rake routes`? I guess it won't be readable in a comment, so you can paste it somewhere else..

Comment: here have you pic of my rake routes. http://forumbilder.se/images/4c5201212054Pd885.jpg

Comment: It looks weird. How about `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails? Can you post your model?

If it's the newest version of Rails, you have to whitelist your attributes.

Comment: My model is


    class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
       # attr_accessible :title, :body
       belongs_to :result
     end


how to check my version?

Comment: Look in your Gemfile. If it says gem 'rails', '3.2.3', it's the newest. In that case, you'll have to uncomment the attr_accessible line and add the fields you're trying to set in the form.

Comment: Your player model. It's the commented line.

Comment: they changed you said. but it does 


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :result
end

Comment: whata mens with :title, :body?

Comment: :title and :body would be fields in your Player model. If you don't have those fields (your migration doesn't show them), remove those and replace it with :name, which you are trying to set in your form.

Comment: if I have a t.string = "name" in the migration.
then be atr_: name?

Comment: attr_accessible :name is what I meant

Comment: i write class Player <ActiveRecord :: Base attr_accessible: Namn BELONGS_TO: Resultat end

don't work!

Comment: any other file you want to check over who can play the role?